# Rails Form submitting causing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, sqlite, activerecord

I created this form :

```
<%= form_for @task do |task| %>
    <%= task.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @user.id %>

    <%= task.label :task %>
    <%= task.text_area :task %>

    <%= task.label :deadline %>
    <%= task.text_field :deadline %>

    <%= task.submit "Add" %>
<% end %>
```

and the controller:

```
def new
    @task = Todo.new
  end

  def create
    @task = Todo.new(params[:task])
    if @task.save
        set_flash "Task added"
      redirect_to action: 'index'
    else
        set_flash "Task adding failed, Please try again"
      redirect_to action: 'index'
    end
  end

def set_user
    @user = current_user
end
```

when i submit the form i get this error:

> SQLite3::ConstraintException: todos.user_id may not be NULL: INSERT INTO "todos" ("completed", "created_at", "deadline", "task", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

What is the problem?

**Edit:**

this is the parmaters passed by rails:

```
 {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"oJr4ii4szyBVAacBJDNYcZn8QWGrFij4dF1wqD1Fvic=",
 "todo"=>{"user_id"=>"1",
 "task"=>"Hello World",
 "deadline"=>"03/20/2013"},
 "commit"=>"Add"}
```

and this is the model:

```
attr_accessible :user_id, :deadline, :task, :completed
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the database has informed you, the problem is that the `user_id` field of your `Todo` cannot be nil. Ensure that you associated it with the current user before saving it, perhaps doing something like this in your controller:

```
def create
  @task = Todo.new(params[:task])
  @task.user = current_user
  ...

end
```

Or remove the constraint from your database if you want todos to be creatable without having an associated user.

Comment: The `user_id` isn't nil in the request Parameters and in firebug the `hidden_filed` isn't nil.added the parmaters to the main question

Comment: It might not be accessible in your model, then (check your `attr_accessible` and ensure `user_id` is there). But you don't want to assign the user based on the value of a `hidden_field` anyway: this exposes you to users potentially assigning todos to other users by simply manipulating the data they send in the form.

Comment: I have `user_id` in the `attr_accessible`, i assigned the `user_id` via the controller, however now it throws the same error but instead of the `user_id` value it now asks for the `task` value. **Edit**: assigning all the values via the controller allowed the form to submit successfully

Comment: This is actually happening because you're using `params[:task]` in your controller, but the params are being sent under the `todo` hash. If you change your controller to `params[:todo]` this will work as you expect.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. If you can could you please explain why it passed the hash as `todo` instead of `task`?

Comment: Definitely! It's passed by the name of the model, not the name of the instance variable. If you want to change the name of the params hash, you can do so like this: `<%= form_for @task, :as => :task %>` Then it will be `params[:task]` instead of `params[:todo]`.